# Drupal Commerce Stock Availability or Out of Stock

Tags: entities, rules, commerce

I am working on Drupal Commerce website. Using Commerce Stock I am able to manage the inventory but on product details page I want to print the following.

Availability: In Stock

or

Availability: Out of Stock

Also if possible

Availability: Limited Stock

If I am displaying stock filed its showing number of items available in stock, which I don't want to display.

Is there any way in Drupal I can acheive this task?

Comment: how are you displaying your products? Views, node view modes, other?

Comment: Are you working with Drupal 7 Commerce or Drupal 8 Commerce. If you know, please then tag your question with 7 or 8. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On Drupal 7.61 & Commerce Stock 7.x-2.3 I've solved it with hook_commerce_product_reference_default_delta_alter:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_product_reference_default_delta_alter().
*/
function test_module_commerce_product_reference_default_delta_alter(&$delta, $products) {

foreach ($products as $product) {
  if ($product->commerce_stock['und'][0]['value'] > 0){
    $product->commerce_stock['und'][0]['value'] = "On stock";
  }else {
    $product->commerce_stock['und'][0]['value'] = "Out of stock";
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set these message in **STOCK** manage display of every product variation type. **Store->Configuration->Product variation types->YOUR PRODUCT VARIATION TYPE->Manage display**. Change label as **above** and change format as **Show stock display as message** .Finally change the message on settings on right side of field.